# How to make static array point to NULL

Tags: arrays, c, optimization, struct, null

Is there a possible way to make static array of structs points to NULL since I can't delete arrays and I want to clean the memory?

Suppose we have the following code:

```
struct_x defaultStructX[6];
struct_x requiredStructX [6];
gettingDefaultX(defaultStructX, 6);         

                for (uint8_t i = 0; i <6; i++)
                {
                     setStructX(requiredStructX[i].index, requiredStructX[i].icirate, requiredStructX[i].icis, requiredStructX[i].iei);

                    //error handle case
                    if (status == STATUS_SUCCESS)
                    {
                        writeResponse.writeStatus = status_ok; /*This is another struct not important at this point*/
                    } else
                    {
                        errorHandleQciFlowMeter(defaultStructX, 6);
                        writeResponse.writeStatus = status_nok; 
                        break;
                    }
                }

/*here I want to write code line to clean the defaultStructX from memory. Is it possible? I have tried *defaultStructX[i]= NULL and ##((void*)defaultQciFlowMeter) = NULL; ## and many other methods but it didn't work*/
```

Comment: Arrays are not pointers. If you have a variable of type array, you cannot manually change its lifetime.

Comment: Why do you want to "clean the memory" and what does that even mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a possible way to make static array of stucts points to NULL since I can't delete arrays and I want to clean the memory?

No.  Arrays are not pointers, nor are the elements of your particular arrays pointers, either.  Pointer values cannot be assigned to either the arrays themselves or to the elements, and in particular, `NULL` cannot be assigned to them.

You can overwrite the memory occupied by the array with, say,

```
memset(defaultStructX, 0, sizeof(defaultStructX));
```

That will replace the data previously stored within,<sup>*</sup> which might be useful if those data were sensitive.  The application would then need to assign new, valid values to the array elements before using them again.

Any way around, however, you cannot free the memory of an object with static storage duration, which is any object declared at file scope, outside all functions, or with the `static` qualifier inside a function.  The entire point of static storage duration is for objects' lifetimes to be the entire duration of the program's run.  If you want to be able to release the memory then you should allocate space for your arrays dynamically, or, if it works for your particular application, automatically (as a local variable of a well-chosen function).

---

<sup>*</sup> In principle.  As @chux noted in comments, it may be the case that the compiler chooses to optimize out such an overwrite, which it might do if it could determine that the zeroed out data were never read.  If this is a concern, then the best mitigation would probably be to declare the arrays `volatile`.

Comment: I know it’s extremely common but strictly speaking this `memset` method can cause UB if the struct contains any pointers, which are subsequently compared to `NULL`, since C does not specify that the null pointer is represented in memory by zero-valued bytes (and some platforms indeed use different values). The safe way of zeroing out an array of structs at runtime is to use `memset(defaultStructX, default, sizeof defaultStructX / sizeof default);`, where `default` is a statically-allocated copy of `struct_x`.

Comment: Quite so, @KonradRudolph, but irrelevant here.  The point of the `memset()` in this case would be to *destroy* the data, on the assumption that it may be sensitive and so must not be retained in memory.  That does not imply leaving the objects in a consistent state.  If there were a desire to reuse them then it would be an application responsibility to set new, valid values.

Comment: @KonradRudolph `memset()` [idea]()https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63939174/how-to-make-static-array-point-to-null#comment113065229_63939417 only works if `sizeof (struct_x)` is 1 or if all bytes in `struct_x` are the same.

Comment: @John, `memset()` is insufficient to zero-ing sensitive data as the `memset()` may be optimized out.  A loop zero-ing via `volatile char *` is an alternative.

Comment: One can only do so much, @chux.  In a situation where a compiler decides (correctly) that it can optimize out the `memset()`, I don't think there could be any other alternative for clearing the data from memory that the compiler was unable, in principle, to optimize out as well.  The basis for such a decision would need to be that the memory was not read again after having been written, and that's insensitive to the mechanism by which the memory was written.

Comment: From time-to-time, I have seen application specific function solutions, yet using `volatile` avoids being optimized out.  [e.g.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63942708/2410359)

Comment: @chux Yes, of course `memset` is the wrong function; it should be `memcpy`, and it needs to be called in a loop for an array. Brain fart. — The point is that John’s solution works fine to zero out memory to hide it from view. But to *default* memory (i.e. to make it *usable*), it is necessary to copy actual data into the memory location, because C does not guarantee that zeroed bytes correspond to a valid representation of an object (notably, null pointers).

Answer (score 2):

```
struct_x defaultStructX[6];
struct_x requiredStructX [6];
```

With the above statements, you have reserved memory for the two arrays of structs. This memory will remain allocated to you during the entire lifetime of your program and cannot be de-allocated until your program exits.

However, what you want to store in this memory is completely under your control. What is your definition of 'cleaning from memory'?

Do you haves some sensitive data that you want to erase from memory? You can always [memset](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memset/) them to zero (or any other value) with:

```
memset(defaultStructX, 0x00, sizeof(defaultStructX));
```

Do you want to physically de-allocate the memory? If you want to have control over allocation and deallocation of chunks of memory, you should do so with [malloc](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc) and [free](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/free).

**EDIT:** Apparently the memset() solution can be [derailed by compiler optimizations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63939174/how-to-make-static-array-point-to-null/63939340?noredirect=1#comment113070823_63939340).
[Here](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/MSC06-C.+Beware+of+compiler+optimizations) is a useful description of this issue from the SEI CERT C page.

Comment: "You can always memset them to zero (or any other value) with: memset..." --> [no](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63939174/how-to-make-static-array-point-to-null#comment113070712_63939417).

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica thanks for pointing out - added a note about this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot manually deallocate anything that wasn’t allocated with `malloc`, `calloc`, or `realloc`.  If you declared your arrays at file scope (outside of any function) or with the `static` keyword, then their memory won’t be released until the program terminates.  Otherwise, their memory will be released when the function in which they were declared exits.

You can overwrite elements not currently in use with zeros or some other “not a value” value, but you cannot free the memory they occupy.

Arrays are not pointers.  *Expressions* of array type are converted to pointers as necessary, but the array object itself is not a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a possible way to make static array of structs points to NULL since I can't delete arrays and I want to clean the memory?

No.  Arrays do not *point*.   The array could be cleared.

> I want to write code line to clean the defaultStructX from memory.

Simply assigned zeros to it.

`memset()` can get optimized out if the compiler sees the data was not subsequently read.

Alternative: use a loop with  a pointer to volatile data to avoid loop from being optimized out.

```
volatile unsigned char *vp = defaultStructX;
for (size_t i = 0; i<sizeof defaultStructX; i++ {
  vp[i] = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... On one hand I love the detailed answer offered by John Bollinger and I believe he gave the correct answer for your use case... however...

There is a way to make the statically allocated array **appear to** point to NULL.

Obviously you can't assign `NULL` to an array. However, you can make a statically allocated "Array" **seem** to point to `NULL` by hiding it behind a pointer.

It might look like this:

```
#define STRUCT_X_ARRAY_LENGTH 6
struct_x defaultStructX___[STRUCT_X_ARRAY_LENGTH];
struct_x requiredStructX___[STRUCT_X_ARRAY_LENGTH];
struct_x * defaultStructX = defaultStructX___;
struct_x * requiredStructX = requiredStructX___;
gettingDefaultX(defaultStructX, STRUCT_X_ARRAY_LENGTH);
```

Now you could set the (no longer) "Array" to `NULL` using:

```
defaultStructX = NULL;
requiredStructX = NULL;
```

You could also reset the state (zero out the memory and reassign the correct memory address) using:

```
defaultStructX = defaultStructX___;
requiredStructX = requiredStructX___;
memset(defaultStructX___, 0 , sizeof(defaultStructX___));
memset(defaultStructX___, 0 , sizeof(requiredStructX___));
```

Not that this fits your use case, but it's a good enough technique that others might want to know about it.